# VSTO Word plugin crashes while splitting two tables

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm new to the C#-Topic (PHP-Background) and I'm encountering constantly the same issue with my Word-Plugin. The task is, to split a table into two pieces, if the amount of rows reached a certain breakpoint. To solve this, I just splitted the table, added the exact same headline to table 2, created an invisible table with two columns (they need to be parallel), pasted these 2 splitted tables in column 1,1 and 1,2. This works for a single table, but if there are two or more, it just crashes without any Exception. The only thing I know is, that the Application crashes, just before filling the first headline in the new Table. Maybe a Performance-Problem with 2 or more tables?

Task in Pictures

```
+------------+------------+
| Headline 1 | Headline 2 |
+------------+------------+
| Col 1,1    | Col 1,2    |
| Col 2,1    | Col 2,2    |
| Col 3,1    | Col 3,2    |
+------------+------------+
```

to

```
+------------+------------+    +------------+------------+
| Headline 1 | Headline 2 |    | Headline 1 | Headline 2 |
+------------+------------+    +------------+------------+
| Col 1,1    | Col 1,2    |    | Col 3,1    | Col 3,2    |
| Col 2,1    | Col 2,2    |    +------------+------------+
+------------+------------+
```

and here is my code

```
private long createInvisibleTable() {
    long timestamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
    Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
    doc.Paragraphs.SpaceAfter = 0;
    Word.Table newTable = doc.Tables.Add(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range, 1, 2);
    newTable.AllowAutoFit = true;
    newTable.Descr = timestamp.ToString();
    newTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "1. Tabelle hier einfügen";
    newTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "2. Tabelle hier einfügen";
    return timestamp;
}


private Word.Table getInvisibleTable(long hash) {
    Word.Tables docTables = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables;
    foreach (Word.Table thisTable in docTables) {
        if (thisTable.Tables.Count > 0) {
            this.getInvisibleTable(hash);
        } else if (thisTable.Descr == hash.ToString()) {
            return thisTable;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


private void splitTables(Word.Tables tablesRec)
{
    foreach (Word.Table table in tablesRec)
    {
        if (table.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            this.splitTables(table.Tables);
        }
        else
        {
            int schwellenwert = this.splitTableSchwellenwert;
            double breakPoint = schwellenwert;
            int counter = 0;

            if (table.Rows.Count > schwellenwert)
            {
                try
                {
                    breakPoint = 2 + (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)(table.Rows.Count - 1) / 2);

                    Word.Table tableSplit = table.Split(breakPoint);

                    tableSplit.Range.Select();
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Collapse();
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InsertRowsAbove();

                    foreach (Word.Cell sourceTableCell in table.Rows[1].Cells)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        tableSplit.Cell(1, counter).Range.Text = sourceTableCell.Range.Text;
                    }

                    table.Select();
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Cut();
                    long tableHash = this.createInvisibleTable();
                    Word.Table thisTable = this.getInvisibleTable(tableHash);
                    thisTable.Cell(1, 1).Select();
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.PasteAsNestedTable();

                    tableSplit.Select();
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Cut();
                    thisTable.Cell(1, 2).Select();
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Source: \n" + e.Source);
                    Debug.WriteLine("\n\nMessage: \n" + e.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("\n\nStacktrace: " + e.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line of code, exactly, triggers the crash? If you end code execution just before the crash, where is the SELECTION in the document, exactly? Are you able to manually perform the action that in code causes the crash? My gut feeling is that the tables you're creating are corrupted OR where you're trying to insert the new ones is not a valid position. Your code is lacking useful comments, for example, I'm not clear how getInvisibleTable(tableHash); is supposed to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the recursive function `getInvisibleTable`. It is necessary to loop through all tables, but this function awaits only a `long`, so it was impossible to loop deeper. The solution looks like the following:

```
private Word.Table getInvisibleTable(long hash , Word.Tables tablesRec) {
    Word.Tables docTables = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables;
    foreach (Word.Table thisTable in docTables) {
        if (thisTable.Tables.Count > 0) {
            this.getInvisibleTable(hash, thisTable.Tables);
        } else if (thisTable.Descr == hash.ToString()) {
            return thisTable;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm looking forward to make this function more easy to use. (E.g. declare optional parameter)